# Sum of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_1 =\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3},2x+3y+4z=0\}$ and $V_2 = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3},x+y+z=0\}$. Check if $V_1+V_2=\mathbb{R^3}$.

So, I showed that the vectors $(2,3,4),(1,1,1)$ are linearly independent, but I don't think that that's enough.

Comment: As a first step, try writing out what the elements of $V_{1}+V_{2}$ look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ are planes passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And, since $(2,3,4)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are linear independent, $V_1\neq V_2$. Therefore, $V_1+V_2=\mathbb{R}^3$.